# How to set a common y-axis label for different subplots in the same figure

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot three different subplots inside one figure, and so far I'm just able to set one `ylabel` for each of them, which is pointless because the values depicted in the y axis of each subplot refer to the same variable (Frequency in Hz).

What I would like to know is how to make them all **share the same single y-axis label**.

Here you have the code so you can have a look at what I've done so far:

```
% I defined the variables for the subplots
freq = 2; 
freq2 = 7;
freq3 = 30; % frequency in Hz
time = -1:.001:1; % -1 to 1 seconds in millisecond steps

% Formula for the plots (sinewave formula)
sinewave = 1*sin(2*pi*freq*time + 0);
sinewave2 = 1*sin(2*pi*freq2*time + 0);
sinewave3 = 1*sin(2*pi*freq3*time + 0);

% Different subplots
figure(1), clf
subplot(311);
plot(time,sinewave);

subplot(312);
plot(time,sinewave2);
set(gca,'xlim',[-1.1 1.1],'ylim',[-1.1 1.1]);
hold on;

subplot(313);
plot(time,sinewave3);
set(gca,'xlim',[-1.1 1.1],'ylim',[-1.1 1.1]); 
hold on;

% Now the labels (Which I want to change to show as common for the
% y-axis of the three subplots together)
xlabel('Time (ms)')
ylabel ('Frequency (Hz)')
```

Comment: Use the `ylabel` command after each `plot` command, or within the `set` you are already doing like `set( ..., 'ylabel', 'Frequency (Hz)' )`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that would provide me with one ylabel for each of the subplots. What I want is just one common ylabel for the three of them instead of the same label repeated three times.

Comment: What does it matter? It would look the same... Just keep the ylabel handles someplace and if you want to change all 3 at once do something like `set(yLabelHandleVector,'String','New y-label [Hz]')`. It would be best if you provided an image/illustration of the desired result.

Comment: Note, when doing a 3rows * 1column layout as you are, it would be clearer for the reader to see 3 repeated y labels, and is probably best practise for any published plot. If you really want to have common labels, see the duplicate question as flagged by Sardar